# How do you ensure that each time you click a React Router link, it ensures that the component is rendered in a specific state (via a parent)?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, state, create-react-app, conditional-rendering

In React.js, I was wondering if there's an easy way to **change child components' state from a parent component**? I'll explain the context and the reasons for which I'm asking this below.

My React.js web app has a Navigation bar that works pretty fine. However I noticed a small bug, and it's been frustrating me.

I bootstrapped the app with Create-React-App, so App.js is my root and it has all the route paths in the app (which are used in the navigation bar). The App.js code is below (components have all been imported):

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="App">
          <Navbar />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path = '/' component = {AboutThis} />
            <Route path = '/contact' component = {ContactMe} />
            <Route path = '/app' component = {HowYouFeel} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

This works pretty fine in terms of going to the relevant links. However, both the ContactMe and HowYouFeel components use conditional rendering (where depending on the state of each of these components, a certain other component displays). E.g. When I want to show 'happiness', the state of HowYouFeel is something like 'happy' and as a result, it renders "Happy.js".

The thing is, I noticed that even if "HowYouFeel" starts off with the state "neutral"(and subsequently renders "Neutral.js"), if I click a button on the page to set the state to "Happy", then even if I click the "HowYouFeel" link in the navigation bar after, it stays at this state and **doesn't restore back to "neutral" as I want it to**. To restore the state I have to either refresh, click away to another link and go back, or press a "Try Again" button that I've added to the page in the "Happy" state. While I am happy with the aforementioned, **I want the state to restore to "neutral" every time I click the link in the navbar**.

Below is my Navbar code, if relevant:

```
const Navbar = () => {
    return (
        <nav className="nav-wrapper blue">
            <div className="container">
                <Link to="/" className ="brand-logo">How are you?</Link>
                <ul className="right">
                    <li><NavLink to="/">About</NavLink></li>
                    <li><NavLink to='/app'>How was your day?</NavLink></li>
                    <li><NavLink to='/contact'>Contact</NavLink></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    )
}
```

So, is there any way for me to ensure that **each time these links are clicked** (including in the Navbar), the **components will be restored to their initial state**? Like via passing **props** to the components via either of these two aforementioned?

Please feel free to ask any questions for clarification.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: well explained question. Can't you just use `componentWillUnmount()` to reset the state inside

Comment: Hi @imranhaider, do you mean for componentWillUnmount on each of those two components, insert the relevant setState?

Comment: no, I'm guess that you are neutralizing state in parent component so just pass parameter up in parent component using `componentWillUnmount`

Comment: Hi @imranhaider, sorry, where do I put this componentWillUnmount function (for example, to restore the "neutral" state in "HowYouFeel.js" whenever "How was your day?" is clicked on Navbar)?

Comment: I hope I get the scenario clear, You put the `componentWillUnmount` in child component i.e. `happy.js`

Comment: Hi @imranhaider . I just tried that but it unfortunately doesn't work. My theory is that while Happy.js is rendered to HowYouFeel.js (which is linked to '/app'), if you click on the Navbar link to '/app' ("How are you?") it notices that I already am on '/app' and hence doesn't change the state of HowYouFeel.js (so componentWillUnmount isn't called?). Thus I was wondering if there is a way to ensure state always is 'neutral' whenever I click the link? (e.g. via Navbar.js above, since it seems to be directly related)